# How to put a or condition to .where function in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to check or condition if the author is shakespeare it should return the value or if the year is 1611 also it should return the value.. how is the syntax in underscore

```js
var a=_.where(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) uses `AND` logic.

For a different kind of condition consider using [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), giving it a relevant predicate, eg.

```
var result = _.filter(listOfPlays, function(play){
   return play.author=="Shakespeare" || play.year==1611;
});
```